# How to align a <ul> with an existing menu?

Tags: html-lists

I am having trouble aligning a `<ul><li>`  with an existing navigation.  The more option floats on top of the second option.  How to make them all aligned?

Code:

```
<div id="nav">
<a href="#" id="option">name</a>
<ul id="test"> 

<li><a href="#" id="options1">Post</a> 
  <ul> 

    <li><a id="thestuff" href="#">Post Article</a></li> 
    <li><a id="thestuff" href="#">Post Book</a></li> 
    <li><a id="thestuff" href="#">Post Other</a></li> 
    <li><a id="thestuff" href="#">Post Other</a></li> 
    <li><a id="thestuff" href="#">Post Other</a></li> 
    <li><a id="thestuff" href="#">Post Other</a></li> 
    <li><a id="thestuff" href="#">Post Other</a></li> 
    <li><a id="thestuff" href="#">Post Other</a></li> 
    <li><a id="thestuff" href="#">Post Other</a></li>
    <li><a id="thestuff" href="#">Post Other</a></li> 
  </ul>
   </li> 
  </ul>
  <a href="#" id="option">Article</a>
  <a href="#" id="option">Books</a>
  <a href="#" id="option">Other</a>
  <a href="#" id="option">Other</a>
  <a href="#" id="option">Other</a>
  <a href="#" id="option">Other</a>
  <a href="#" id="option">Other</a>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
 #nav {
 margin-left: 230px;
 margin-top:-19px;
 }

 #option {
 margin-left:20px;
 }
```

I am not using anything for thestuff tag.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `class` for elements that you have more than one of.

By definition an `id` has to be unique

Comment: can you give me an example of what you mean?